# Distributions - please check my solution

Tags: derivatives, distribution-theory

I have to find a derivative in a distributional sense of the following function (known as Cantor's singular function)
$$f(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{l l l l l}
0, & \quad\text{$ x\leq 0 $}\\
1, & \quad\text{$ x\geq 1 $} \\
\frac{1}{2}, & \quad\text{$ x\in[\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3}] $ }\\
\frac{1}{4}, & \quad\text{$ x\in[\frac{1}{9},\frac{2}{9}] $}\\
\frac{3}{4}, & \quad\text{$ x\in[\frac{7}{9},\frac{8}{9}] $}\\
.\\
.\\
.
\end{array} \right.$$

I am not sure if my solution is correct:

Function f is constant on each open interval (($-\infty,0)$, $(1,\infty)$, $(\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3})$, ...), so $f'(x)=0$ a.e. Therefore, $<f'(x),\phi(x)>=0$, for any test function $\phi(x)$.

Is my solution correct? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your reasoning is incorrect. The same reasoning would show that the derivative of the indicator function $\chi_{(0,\infty)}$ is zero, when in fact it is equal to the delta function.

Comment: How should I do this then? Any help is welcome.

Comment: I would use the fact that the distributional derivative of an indicator function $\chi_{(a,b)}$ is equal to $\delta_a - \delta_b$, by the fundamental theorem of calculus. Here $\delta_x$ is the distribution defined by $\delta_x(\phi) = \phi(x)$. Then I would write the Cantor function as an infinite sum of constant multiples of indicator functions and take the derivative term-by-term.

Comment: Let $\mu$ be the unique Borel measure with $\mu((a,b])=f(b)-f(a)$ for all real $a<b$. Then you have $\int f\phi' = -\int \phi d\mu$.